# スプレッドシートでリンクを範囲取得してリンク先を表示させたい

Tags: web-scraping, xpath

この記事の「6. 記事につけられたタグの取得」がうまくいきません

SpreadSheetでスクレイピング。Importxml他、便利な関数9+1 - Qiita
https://qiita.com/ktmg/items/d53440c913e20f8bb34c#6-%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97f4

状況は
A1に`=IMPORTXML()`でA25まで25個のリンクを表示できている
B1に`=IMPORTXML(A1:A25,XPath))`で参照しても最初(A1)しか反映されない

B2からB25にも反映してほしいのですがうまくいきません。
A2以降のXPathが違うのかと思い確認したのですが合っていました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。コピペでも結果は同じになるんですが、記事元だと値は違いますが **A1:A25** のように範囲選択で一括処理しているのです。それが機能してない理由がわからないのです

Answer (score 0):

B1に =IMPORTXML(A1,XPath))  という式を入力してから、B1をコピー。
そして、B2からB25を選択してペースト。

そうすれば、B2に =IMPORTXML(A2,XPath))、B3に =IMPORTXML(A3,XPath))、というように式が入るのでB2からB25にタグが表示されませんか？